# How to best clear an Android ViewModel when the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am currently overriding `ViewModel.onCleared()` to clean up my ViewModel to prevent any leaks (in this case to remove any files from the app's internal storage that have not been used).

That works totally fine when the ViewModel's activity is finished explicitly. But since `onDestroy()` is not called when the app is killed `onCleared()` is neither.

My intention (at the moment) is not to save any data, I just don't want any data leaks, neither when the system kills my process nor when the user kills it.

**What is working**

1. The activity is started and the user takes a picture which is saved
   in the app's internal storage.
2. The user leaves the activity without
   saving.
3. The activity is destroyed and `ViewModel.onCleared()` is
   called which deletes the unused picture.

**What is not working** (but could be solved by using `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()`

1. The activity is started and the user takes a picture which is saved
   in the app's internal storage.
2. The activity's process is killed by the system for whatever reason.
3. Neither `Activity.onDestroy` nor `ViewModel.onCleared()` is called.

**What is also not working**

1. The activity is started and the user takes a picture which is saved
   in the app's internal storage.
2. The user kills the app by swiping.
3. Neither `Activity.onDestroy` nor `ViewModel.onCleared()` is called.

I fear I will have to persist the file names that need to be cleaned up to solve the third case, but this feels very extreme and I was hoping that there was a more intelligent way using the lifecycle methods.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to make sure that `ViewModel.onCleared()` is called under all circumstances.

I solved my specific problem by saving the files first into the cache directory and moving them to my image directory only if it is confirmed that they are needed. This way there still is a way to clean up any left over files in the cache if one of the edge cases occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, do you need to save some data when activity is disrupted? If so, then the best way to implement this is onSaveInstanceState (). In ViewModel it is convenient to keep all the data that you need to form a screen. They will live when the screen is rotated, but will die when the application is killed by the system.

Comment: No, I don't want to save any data. I want to make sure, that a picture that has been taken with the camera and has not yet been associated with an entity will be removed from the app's internal storage.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are talking about. Can you explain better, preferably with code

Comment: Maybe in ViewModel.onCleared () you are clearing resources and want to make sure that they will be cleared anyway? ViewModel.onCleared () should be called anyway when activity is disrupted.So you don’t need to worry about it.

Comment: No, ViewModel.onCleared() is only called when the activity is destroyed, but this does not happen on system initiated process death or when the user kills the app. I will edit my question and try and clarify.

Comment: And, after all, if the process is killed, then why free up resources or are you doing something different in ViewModel.onCleared?

Comment: Or do you need to save data when the application dies?

Comment: No, I don't need to save data, I want to make sure that there are no abandoned files. Otherwise there are scenarios where the app's storage gets polluted which pictures that can never be deleted, since there is no reference to them anymore.

Comment: Why can't you delete a file right after all the actions (when the file is no longer needed?)

Comment: No, the file belongs to a newly created entity and I just want to delete it if the creation gets canceled or aborted (for whatever reason).

Comment: If in your case this is not possible, then you can create a database in which to add all the files and when starting the application check if there are any files to delete

Comment: I don’t know if this is acceptable for your application, but with every start you could clear the internal memory,. if this is unacceptable then the option with saving the path to the files, I think the best